An injection from the set of normal subgroups to subsets of irreducible representations
Some things I understand to be true:
(1) A finite dimensional $\mathrm{C}^*$-algebra $A$ is of the form
$$A\cong \bigoplus_{j=1}^NM_{n_j}(\mathbb{C})\qquad (n_j\in \mathbb{N}).$$
(2) With respect to this notation, each ideal $I\subseteq A$ is given by a subset $S_I\subseteq \{1,2,\dots,N\}$:
$$I=\bigoplus_{j\in S_{I}}M_{n_j}(\mathbb{C})$$
So, for example the zero ideal is given by $\emptyset$, the full ideal given by $\{1,2,\dots,N\}$, etc. Thus there are $2^N$ ideals.

(3) The quotients $A/I$ are isomorphic to those factors in the complement of $S_I$, so
$$A/I\cong \bigoplus_{j\not\in S_I}M_{n_j}(\mathbb{C}).$$
(4) The group algebra $\mathbb{C}G$ of a finite group $G$ is a finite dimensional $\mathrm{C}^*$-algebra. The set $\{1,2,\dots,N\}$ can be given by the equivalence class of irreducible unitary representations $\mathrm{Irr}(G)$, and, for $\alpha\in \mathrm{Irr}(G)$, $n_\alpha=d_\alpha$, the dimension of the representation given by $\alpha$:
$$\mathbb{C}G\cong \bigoplus_{\alpha\in \mathrm{Irr}(G)}M_{d_\alpha}(\mathbb{C}).$$
(5) Quotients $G\to H$, given by $G/N\cong H$, for some normal subgroup $N\lhd G$, correspond to quotients of the group algebra $\mathbb{C}G\to B$. Therefore $B\cong \mathbb{C}G/I$, for some ideal $I\subseteq \mathbb{C}G$. Therefore every normal subgroup $N\lhd G$ corresponds to an ideal $I_N\subseteq \mathbb{C}G$, and therefore to a subset of the index set, a subset of $\mathrm{Irr}(G)$.
Thus we have an injection from the set of normal subgroups of $G$ to the subsets of $\mathrm{Irr}(G)$. For example, I believe $G\mapsto \mathrm{Irr}(G)\backslash \{\tau\}$, the trivial representation; and $\{e\}\mapsto \emptyset$, the empty-set giving the zero ideal.

Is the italicised above correct?

If it is not correct where does the reasoning fall down? If it is correct I assume this is well known: is it an observation that leads anywhere?
Context: I just want to explain briefly where this question came from. I have some algebras $A_n$ indexed by $n\in\mathbb{N}$. As it happens, they are infinite dimensional, so the above is largely moot in terms of this question, but anyway. For each $n$ we have the commutator ideal $J_n\subset A_n$ and another ideal $I_n\subset A_n$. The ideal $I_n$ is generated by a single projection $p\in A_n$. My question is about the possible inclusion $J_n\subset I_n$. In the finite dimensional case it is easy enough, back in $\oplus_{j=1}^N$, to identify the commutator ideal:
$$J_n\leftrightarrow \left[S\subset\{1,2,\dots,N\}\text{ such that }n_j>1\text{ for }j\in S\right].$$
Let $p_j$ be the unit in $M_{n_j}(\mathbb{C})$. If $J_n\subset I_n$, and $I_n=\langle p_n\rangle$, and in my head for each of the $p_j$ coming from summands in the commutator ideal, it should be the case that $p_jp_n\neq 0$. Else that summand would give something in $I_n$ but not in $J_n$.

I feel like this is written in a more complicated way than is needed, but yes, the statement you wrote down is true. (I guess with the way you’re defining this, the normal subgroup ${e}$ should have corresponded to $\varnothing$ since there’s no kernel and $G$ should have corresponded to $\mathrm{Irr}(G)\setminus{\tau}$, but the spirit of the statement is right at least.) The correspondence is injective because different normal subgroups correspond to different kernels and therefore different collections of irreps.

But this can be obtained without appealing to $C^\ast$ algebra theory. The subset of irreps corresponding to $N \trianglelefteq G$ you wrote down is easily seen to be just the complement of the irreps that quotient through $G/N$. (Also, the correspondence is not surjective. Just think of a nontrivial simple group.)

Oh yeah, I have those things the wrong way around. I am actually less interested in the group theory, more worried that my algebra basics had some misunderstanding.

Your understanding seems fine. By the way, your understanding in the commutator ideal part is also fine. The ideal generated by $p$ in a direct sum of matrix algebras is exactly the direct sum of those summands in which $p$ is nonzero. So indeed, $J \subset \langle p \rangle$ iff $p_jp \neq 0$ for every unit $p_j$ of $M_{n_j}(\mathbb{C})$ where $M_{n_j}(\mathbb{C})$ is a summand in $J$. This is a lot more complicated in infinite dimensions though.

(Though the same argument would work if the algebra is a finite direct sum of simple algebras.)
